# How can i filter data from different tables and write List<> method in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, typescript, forms, methods

How can I write the sql query I wrote below in .net or c# with the list method?? or how can i write list method in .net desktop application?

```sql
select d.ParentID, c.ID as CategoryID, p.ID ProductID 
from Categories c, Categories d, Products p 
where c.ID=d.ParentID
    and p.CategoryID=c.ID
ORDER BY 1,2,3
```

Comment: Please post code of what you have tried

Comment: Is this an entity framework question? Or do you just want raw sql?

Comment: `select d.ParentID, c.ID ... where c.ID = d.ParentID` seems pointless

Comment: yes, this is an entity framework question, but it could be any answer written in c#. It doesn't have to be an entity framework. @JeremyLakeman

Comment: Let me share the version of the question before it was converted to sql. I hope there is no error in my sql query. "I'm trying to write the code that retrieves the category and all its subcategories with the given ID from the database and returns it as a List type."  @CaiusJard

Comment: Instead of using `c` and `d` i'd recommend using eg `childCat` and `parentCat`. This would help keep straight in your mind eg `SELECT childCat.Id as ChildCatId, parentCat.Id as ParentCatId .. FROM Category childCat INNER JOIN Category parentCat ON childCat.ParentId = parentCat.Id..` - Also note the use of ANSI92 join syntax, which has been the preferred way to write joins since 1992, 30 years ago

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, i have a more understandable sql query now !! :) @CaiusJard

Comment: If you then want to run that query in a desktop applciation, probably the simplest way is to use Dapper. Something like `using var c = new SqlConnection("conn str here"); await c.QueryAsync<(int ChildCatId, int ParentCatId, int ProdId)>("SELECT ...");` would do it

Comment: Yes I want to run it in desktop application. I've done the connection parts, I just have to get the data from tables and print it as a List<> type. But I don't know how to get data from different tables and list them in a single list. @CaiusJard

Comment: Just mentioned it there above.. It's only two lines of code. Spend some time on https://dapper-tutorial.net/